# Buffer.BlockCopy in WinRT

Tags: .net, windows-runtime

Is there a Buffer.BlockCopy equivalent function or strategy in WinRT? We cannot use Array.Copy because we need to avoid boundaries checking.

We need to port a legacy .Net code that actually copies a byte array to a template array working like a BitConverter. The original code is:

```
public T GetValue(int index)
{
    T[] vals = new T[1];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(Buffer.ToBytes(), index * UnitSize, vals, 0, UnitSize);
    return vals[0];
}
```

Kind regards

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to avoid boundaries checking? If it's because of performance, are you sure `Array.Copy()` is too slow and `Buffer.BlockCopy()` would help you?

Comment: Unfortunately, it has nothing to do with the performance. We need to port a legacy .Net code that actually copies a byte array to a template array working like a BitConverter. The original code is: 
public T GetValue(int index) {
T[] vals = new T[1];
Buffer.BlockCopy(Buffer.ToBytes(), index * UnitSize, vals, 0, UnitSize);
return vals[0];
}

Comment: And `T` can be any type or is it from a set of certain types?

Comment: It is one of the following types: double, float, byte, ushort, int, short, uint.

Answer (score 0):

System.Buffer.BlockCopy works just fine in my WinRT app